# How to Convert DataLoadOptions to human readable string?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to debug a faulting process.  The error occurs when our LINQ to SQL data context has its LoadOptions updated.  Is there a way to convert the value of the DataLoadOptions object into human readable text?

Here's the error message:

```
EXCEPTION (InvalidOperationException):
    Setting load options is not allowed after results have been returned from a query.
INNER EXCEPTION:
STACKTRACE:
    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.set_LoadOptions(DataLoadOptions value)
```

Here's the code:

```cs
if (loadOptions != null)
{
    try
    {
        Domain.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log and continue
        LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Error, ex);
        LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Warning, "Error setting DataContext LoadOptions, related data may not be loaded.");
    }
}
```

The method with the code above is called from other places, which may pass in a `DataLoadOption` object.  If present, the `DataLoadOption` object's `LoadWith` method will have been called at least once, and possibly its `AssociateWith` method.

To assist with my debugging, I'd like to write all the `LoadWith` and `AssociateWith` options to our logs.  Alternatively, anything that would help me determine the chain of calls leading to this method would also help, as I'm sure the LINQ to SQL DataContext is being used prior to calling this method.  (In the above code `Domain` is our DataContext.)

Comment: I've edited the question to add some more details and hopefully clarify things.

Comment: This all indicates that the context's lifespan is too long. You should use one context instance for one task and then dispose it. Maybe you can achieve what you want by reflecting on non-public `DataLoadOptions` members (public members don't offer any hooks), but then you're not getting to the root of your problem.

Comment: @GertArnold you may be right.  I've worked around the problem by adding statements to log the call stack between the root of the application and the method with the `catch` block.  That allowed me to locate where the data context was being previously used and determine an appropriate point to initialize a new one.  Unfortunately, when we started this project a few years ago, I and the other developers were all new to LINQ to SQL and tried to minimize instantiation of new objects. This practice has back-fired on us...